# Retrieving the Last ID from the Database from a Specified Category in String Value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve the last ID from the database and increment it by one. My problem is that I am not able to retrieve it in a particular category. For instance, I have categories with a string value of A, B and C. The category with a string value of A will return only id starting from 1 as 10001, 10002 and the last ID to be retrieved is 10002 plus 1 so that the ID to be displayed is 10003.
Category "B" will return 20002 and category "C" will return 30002.
Here is my code:

```
 <?php

  $con =     mysql_connect("server","username","password","db_name") or die (mysql_error());

  mysql_select_db($con, 'db_name');
  $sql = "Select `id` from `tbl_violation` WHERE `category` = 'A' ORDER BY `category` DESC LIMIT 1";

 $result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, $con))
 {
                $i = $row['id'];
                $i++;
                echo "DLR - " .$i;
 }  
 ?>
```

The error is this:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...

Notice: Undefined variable: i in ...

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve maximal values for each category or only one category?
also do not use mysql functions, rather mysqli or even better use PDO

Comment: The last ID for each category Sir. Say, 2002 for category "B" or 3005 for Category "C".  @flynorc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I must say again... Stay away from `mysql_connect()` and all other mysql_* functions. If you want a simple fix, just replace it with mysqli_ functions and make sure you escape ALL user provided input. [A bit of reading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) But I would recommend to look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

That out of the way, your MYSQL problem is easy. You want to GROUP the elements so all the rows with same category column are groupped together and then select the maximum for each group. Your SQL would then be:

```
SELECT category, MAX(id) AS highest_id FROM tbl_violation GROUP BY category;
```

see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cf34/1) I made with a similar table.

You can then access the results you get from mysql**i**_query function the same way you do now...

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, $con))
 {
        $i = $row['highest_id'];
        $i++;
        $category = $row['category'];
        echo "$category - $i";
 }
```

Comment: Hi Sir! :) Thanks for the help! :) I'll read more about mysqli and PDO. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT MAX to get the highest id. I am assuming that id is not unique. If so, remove the WHERE statement from the query. Try the following.

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("server","username","password","db_name") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database");
    $sql = "Select MAX(`id`) from `tbl_violation` WHERE `category` = 'A";

    $result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $i = $row['id'];
        echo "DLR - " .$i++;
    }  
?>
```

Also I would like to add that I agree with flynorc. Use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: It's saying :     
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ... on line 7 @Dais

Comment: Hi Sir thanks for the response. The id is unique. If I remove the where statement from the query how will I be able to filter data with the particular category I want to retrieve and get its last id? @Dais

Comment: Can you explain, why are you incrementing the retrieved id?

Comment: Because I am going to create a new record with the id incremented from the last id with a specified format Sir. I have three fields in the database naming id, violation name and violation category. Each violation category has an id differ from each other as I mention earlier. Category "A" has a starting number of 2 as 20001 and "B" as 30001, 30002.. I used a drop down menu here where the user can select the particular category and automatically retrieved a unique id in every selection. @Dais

Comment: Hi Sir. Thank you for the help. I'll bear mind what you guys taught me and read more about PDO and mysqli so that I can adapt with the changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Instead of

```
ORDER BY `category` DESC
```